# OMNeT++ Documentation Where?

Tags: omnet++

I couldn't find documentation resources for OMNeT++ such as video learning, Books, that cover wireless sensor network localization, I need someway to cover the RSSI localization and ToA (time of arrival), please any thing can help even advice.

Answer (score 1):

The [TicToc Tutorial](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/) is a very good starting point. It starts with very basic stuff like "What is a model?", but also shows how to define custom messages or how to record statistics.

You also might want to have a look to the [INET Framework](https://inet.omnetpp.org/) for the wireless sensor network part.

Answer (score 0):

I think when studied OMNeT++ I used this material:

https://docs.omnetpp.org/